# numpy.max or max ? Which one is faster?

Tags: python, numpy, runtime, max, min

In python, which one is faster ?

```
numpy.max(), numpy.min()
```

or

```
max(), min()
```

My list/array length varies from 2 to 600. Which one should I use to save some run time ?

Comment: You should definitely test and find out for your specific scenario, but my first instinct is that it would depend on whether your iterables are "vanilla" python iterables or numpy iterables.

Comment: If the data are in a **`list`**, I'd use vanilla `max`. If they are in a numpy **`array`** I'd use `numpy.max`. Converting a list to a numpy array is a pretty expensive operation

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Well from my timings it follows if you already have numpy array `a` you should use `a.max` (the source tells it's the same as `np.max` if `a.max` available). But if you have built-in list then most of the time takes *converting* it into np.ndarray => that's why `max` is better in your timings.

In essense: if `np.ndarray` then `a.max`, if `list` and no need for all the machinery of `np.ndarray` then standard `max`.

Answer (score 44):

I was also interested in this and tested the three variants with [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) (a little project of mine). Result: You're not going wrong with `a.max()`.

[image]

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
import numpy as np
import perfplot

b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=np.random.rand,
    kernels=[max, np.max, lambda a: a.max()],
    labels=["max(a)", "np.max(a)", "a.max()"],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(25)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
)
b.show()
```

Answer (score 13):

It's probably best if you use something like the Python [timeit module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) to test it for yourself. That way you can test your own data in your own environment, rather than relying on third parties with various test data and environments which aren't necessarily representative of yours.

Comment: I tried that on a random list of 600 floating point numbers.
    || np.max() + np.min() -> 1.093 msec ||
    max() + min() -> 0.092 msec

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.min` and `numpy.max` have slightly different semantics (and call signatures) to the builtins, so the choice shouldn't be to do with speed. Use the numpy versions if you need to be able to handle multidimensional data sanely. If you're just using Python lists or other things that don't know about dimensionality, use the builtins.