# Should I use np.absolute or np.abs?

Tags: python, numpy, absolute-value

Numpy provides both [`np.absolute`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html) and the alias [`np.abs`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/698ddea57384e12bbdea18592b36b33566ca49b0/numpy/core/__init__.py#L60) defined via

```
from .numeric import absolute as abs
```

which seems to be in obvious violation of [the zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

So I'm guessing that there is a good reason for this.

I have personally been using `np.abs` in almost all of my code and looking at e.g. the number of search results for [np.abs](https://www.google.se/search?safe=off&q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com+%22np.abs%22&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com+%22np.abs%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3492.3722.0.4098.3.3.0.0.0.0.94.204.3.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0.6tR-xgAcgXk) vs [np.absolute](https://www.google.se/search?safe=off&q=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com+%22np.absolute%22&oq=site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com+%22np.absolute%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...88032.88555.0.88657.5.4.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..5.0.0.x7feo4fakBo) on Stack Overflow it seems like an overwhelming majority does the same (2130 vs 244 hits).

Is there any reason i should preferentially use `np.absolute` over `np.abs` in my code, or should I simply go for the more "standard" `np.abs`?

Comment: I think this is purely a matter of preference - the functionality *should* be completely identical

Comment: Then why does `np.absolute` exist?

Comment: `np.absolute` was introduced first in the API.  Rather than breaking code, they aliased it to `np.abs`

Comment: The plain python `abs(x)` also works, since it delegates the task to the `x.__abs__` method.

Comment: Why builtin `abs` works, https://stackoverflow.com/q/20953127

Answer (score 101, accepted):

It's likely because there a built-in functions with the same name, [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#abs). The same is true for `np.amax`, `np.amin` and `np.round_`.

The aliases for the NumPy functions [`abs`, `min`, `max` and `round`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.1/numpy/core/__init__.py#L59-L60) are only defined in the top-level package.

So `np.abs` and `np.absolute` are completely identical. It doesn't matter which one you use.

There are several advantages to the short names: They are shorter and they are known to Python programmers because the names are identical to the built-in Python functions. So end-users have it easier (less to type, less to remember).

But there are reasons to have different names too: NumPy (or more generally 3rd party packages) sometimes need the Python functions `abs`, `min`, etc. So inside the package they define functions with a different name so you can still access the Python functions - and just in the top-level of the package you expose the "shortcuts". Note: Different names are not the only available option in that case: One could work around that with the Python module [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) to access the built-in functions if one shadowed a built-in name.

It might also be the case (but that's pure speculation on my part) that they originally only included the long-named functions `absolute` (and so on) and only added the short aliases later. Being a large and well-used library the NumPy developers don't remove or deprecate stuff lightly. So they may just keep the long names around because it could break old code/scripts if they would remove them.

Comment: _"But there are reasons to have different names"_ That's not actually the best way how to avoid name shadowing, is it? One can simply prepend a module name in front of the function name.

Comment: @Jeyekomon I didn't mean to imply it's the best approach or even a good one. It's just one possibility. I guess the question how to approach that simply cannot be changed anymore because NumPy tries to be backwards-compatible. So any discussion about which one would be better/the best makes no sense in that context anymore.

Answer (score 16):

There also is [Python's built-in `abs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs), but really all those functions are doing the same thing. They're even exactly equally fast! (This is not the case for other functions, like [`max()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43229430/353337).)

[image]

Code to reproduce the plot:

```py
import numpy as np
import perfplot


def np_absolute(x):
    return np.absolute(x)


def np_abs(x):
    return np.abs(x)


def builtin_abs(x):
    return abs(x)


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=np.random.rand,
    kernels=[np_abs, np_absolute, builtin_abs],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(25)],
    xlabel="len(data)",
)
b.save("out.png")
b.show()
```

Comment: I suspect the identical performance is due to numpy arrays using the `__abs__` magic method, which `abs()` calls if defined.

Comment: This answer should have more upvotes!  Speed comparison is always super helpful

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of numpy.absolute](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html) states that `numpy.abs` is a shorthand. Therefore, the functions are identical.

The preferred version is `numpy.abs` as it is part of the [array api](https://data-apis.org/array-api/latest/API_specification/generated/array_api.abs.html#abs). This means it is the common name agreed upon by the major packages.

I cannot find any deprecation notice, but I expect `numpy.absolute` to be removed in future (personal opinion).