# Difference between max and np.max

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, max

I have a question on the difference between just using max(list array) and np.max(list array).

Is the only difference here the time it takes for Python to return the code?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943088/numpy-max-or-max-which-one-is-faster

Comment: Np.max is not intended to take a list array (it can). Look up ndarray, and after looking at the link in the comment above it will make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "list array"? Python has lists. NumPy has arrays. They're different types.

Answer (score 2):

They may differ in edge cases, such as a list containing NaNs.

```
import numpy as np
a = max([2, 4, np.nan])     # 4
b = np.max([2, 4, np.nan])  # nan
```

NumPy propagates NaN in such cases, while the behavior of Python's `max` is less certain.

There are also subtle issues regarding data types:

```
a = max([10**n for n in range(20)])     # a is an integer
b = np.max([10**n for n in range(20)])  # b is a float
```

And of course running time differences documented in [numpy.max or max ? Which one is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943088/numpy-max-or-max-which-one-is-faster)

Generally, one should use `max` for Python lists and `np.max` for NumPy arrays to minimize the number of surprises.  For instance, my second example is not really about `np.max` but about the data type conversion: to use `np.max` the list is first converted to a NumPy array, but elements like `10**19` are too large to be represented by NumPy integer types so they become floats.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend relying on the behaviour of Python's `max` with respect to NaNs. I suspect it's entirely an accident of the implementation.

Comment: And indeed, `max(nan, 1.2)` is `nan`, not `1.2`. Python's `max` _doesn't_ explicitly ignore NaN entries; it's just that most of the time the comparison it's using internally goes the right way so that the `nan` doesn't get picked up as the max-so-far.