# What is the difference between np.min and min?

Tags: python, numpy

I have trying to learn Python on datacamp. When I run statistical codes with agg - like min, max - I realized that it is the same result with using np with these codes. But I can not use mean and median methods without np.

So,

1. is there any difference between np.min and min , np.max and max?
2. why don't median and mean work without numpy?

Code:

```
unemp_fuel_stats = sales.groupby("type")["unemployment", 
              "fuel_price_usd_per_l"].agg([np.min, np.max, np.mean, np.median])
```

Result:

```
unemployment                      fuel_price_usd_per_l  
amin   amax   mean median                 amin   amax   mean median
type  
A           3.879  8.992  7.973  8.067                0.664  1.107  0.745  0.735
B           7.170  9.765  9.279  9.199                0.760  1.108  0.806  0.803
```

Another result:

```
unemployment        fuel_price_usd_per_l  
min    max                  min    max
type  
A           3.879  8.992                0.664  1.107
B           7.170  9.765                0.760  1.108
```

Comment: one is plain python, the other is numpy-datastructures-aware.

Comment: 1 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943088/numpy-max-or-max-which-one-is-faster

2 - You can use mean and median without numpy `.agg(['min', 'max', 'mean', 'median'])`

Comment: See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html#numpy.amin, for example. `np.min` can do much more than `min` alone.

Comment: `from statistics import mean, median`, not restricted to `numpy` ;)

Comment: @It_is_Chris Is that using pandas?

Comment: @MichaelCao yes, `sales` appears to be a pd.DataFrame and you can just do `.agg(['min', 'max', 'mean', 'median'])` and not use `numpy` -- `pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [2,5,6]]).groupby(0).agg(['min', 'max', 'mean', 'median'])`

Comment: @It_is_Chris that is almost certainly using the `numpy` versions, it isn't clear what you mean "without `numpy`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`min` is the [builtin python function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and `numpy.min` is [another min function that is in the numpy package](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amin.html#numpy.amin). They act similarly but different.

Given a single list, they will act the same:

```
print(np.min([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
print(min([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))

1
1
```

However, given multiple arguments, `numpy.min` will throw an error as the first argument must be array-like. `min` will simply return the minimum of all elements.

```
print(min(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

try:
    print(np.min(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

1
output must be an array
```

`numpy.min` can take the minimum along a specific axis of a multi-dimensional array (which uses multiple square brackets) or the minimum of all elements. `min` will simply given the minimum list (though I forget how they're ordered).

```
twod_array = [[1, 2, 5],
              [3, 7, 5],
              [10, 5, 7]]

print(min(twod_array))
print(np.min(twod_array))
print(np.min(twod_array, axis = 0)) # Minimum of each column
print(np.min(twod_array, axis = 1)) # Minimum of each row

[1, 2, 5]
1
[1 2 5]
[1 3 5]
```

Hope that was enlightening. The tl;dr is that they are simply different functions with the same name. It's good to use `import numpy as np` to differentiate `min` from `np.min`. Using something like `from numpy import min` will cause ambiguity as to which function is actually being used.

Python has no builtin `median` or `mean` but `numpy` has `numpy.median` and `numpy.mean`